# Microsoft Graph API, deleting authentication method "Microsoft Authenticator" Returns 403 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to delete a user's Microsoft Authenticator Authentication Method (`#microsoft.graph.microsoftAuthenticatorAuthenticationMethod`) from any user's list of authentication methods. However, I keep receiving a 403 Forbidden error.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
async deleteUserAuthenticationMethod(email, authId, accessToken) {
    const query = `/users/${email}/authentication/microsoftAuthenticatorMethods/${authId}`

    await azure.graph.delete(query, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });

    return 'Authentication method deleted successfully';              
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

The Microsoft Graph API App has been granted the following permissions:

[image]

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user under which you are running this needs to have the *Authentication Administrator* assigned. And if the target user holds any admin role, you need the *Privileged Authentication Administrator* role instead.